# Creating buttons dependent on input, getting user data

Tags: python, button, tkinter

Relative noob to Python, still learning all the ins and outs, but I'm learning.  I'm diving into GUI for the first time for a personal project I'm working on.  (I'm a linguistics grad student and this will greatly improve my ability to research.)  I know about Tkinter and the Button class (basically, that they exist), but I need some help to get me started.  I think once I know the magic words, I'll be able to adapt it to the situation I need.

Basically, I have sample text excerpt of about 180 words.  What I am looking to do is figure out a way to create a GUI interface such that each individual word in the 180-word excerpt appears as a separate button, and the user is prompted to, for example, click the verb.  The value that is clicked gets stored, and I then go on to whatever my next question is.

What I need to know:
How to create the buttons depending on whatever the text is.  (I'm assuming each button will need a different variable name.)
-Would it matter if the length of one excerpt differs from another?  (I'm assuming not.)
-Would it matter if there are several of the same words within the excerpt?  (I'm assuming not, since you could use indexing to remember where the word clicked is in the original excerpt.)
How to get the data stored depending on the button clicked.
How to clean the slate and go on to whatever my next question would be.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Hi, and first, welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately, your question is a bit vague for this site. If you could post some code you have tried with a specific question relating to what in the code you don't understand or is not working, then we can help you out.

Comment: Dear @user2974982 if you think the posted answer solved your problem or at least it was a useful clue to find the solution you were looking for, please don't hesitate to accept it. If you don't know how to accept an answer, here you can find more information about it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a small example and demo -- it has everything you need to start your program. See the comments inside the code:

[image]

```
import tkinter

app = tkinter.Tk()

# Create a set for all clicked buttons (set prevents duplication)
clicked = set()
# Create a tuple of words (your 180 verb goes here)
words = 'hello', 'world', 'foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'egg', 'spam', 'ham'

# Button creator function
def create_buttons( words ):
    # Create a button for each word
    for word in words:
        # Add text and functionality to button and we are using a lambda
        # anonymous function here, but you can create a normal 'def' function
        # and pass it as 'command' argument
        button = tkinter.Button( app,
                                 text=word,
                                 command=lambda w=word: clicked.add(w) )
        # If you have 180 buttons, you should consider using the grid()
        # layout instead of pack() but for simplicity I used this one for demo
        button.pack()

# For demo purpose I binded the space bar, when ever
# you hit it, the app will print you out the 'clicked' set
app.bind('<space>', lambda e: print( *clicked ))

# This call creates the buttons
create_buttons( words )

# Now we enter to event loop -> the program is running
app.mainloop()
```

---

***EDIT:***

Here is the code without the *lambda expressions*:

```
import tkinter

app = tkinter.Tk()

# Create a set for all clicked buttons (set prevents duplication)
clicked = set()
# Create a tuple of words (your 180 verb goes here)
words = 'hello', 'world', 'foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'egg', 'spam', 'ham'

# This function will run when pressing the space bar
def on_spacebar_press( event ):
    print( 'Clicked words:', *clicked )

# Button creator function
def create_buttons( words ):
    # Create a button for each word
    for word in words:
        # This function will run when a button is clicked
        def on_button_click(word=word):
            clicked.add( word )
        # Add button
        button = tkinter.Button( app,
                                 text=word,
                                 command=on_button_click )
        # If you have 180 buttons, you should consider using the grid()
        # layout instead of pack() but for simplicity I used this one for demo
        button.pack()

# Binding function tp space bar event
app.bind('<space>', on_spacebar_press)

# This call creates the buttons
create_buttons( words )

# Now we enter to event loop -> the program is running
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: OP is noob. Maybe You should bind button to normal 'def' (as you suggest) to show more.

Comment: You are probably right @furas I added the *lambda-free* version too!